# 'Expected expression before double' error after calling an user-defined function

Tags: c, user-defined-functions

I'm working on a code that should display the area of a triangle in a coordinate system, with the angles' coordinates inputted from the keyboard. I am still a beginner in C programming, so this is my first time using a user-defined function. However, after searching the internet for the solution to this error, I am still confused as to where is my mistake.  Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double area(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f);

int main()
{
    double ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, Area;
    scanf ("%f%f%f%f%f%f", &ax, &ay, &bx, &by, &cx, &cy);
    Area = double area(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy);
    printf (" area %f", Area);
    return 0;
}

double area(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f)

{
    double bb1, ab1, cb1, T1L1, T1L2, T1L3;
    bb1=d-b;
    cb1=e-c;
    T1L2=sqrt(pow(bb1, 2)+pow(cb1, 2)); //first side of the triangle
    ab1=e-a-cb1;
    T1L1=sqrt(pow(bb1, 2)+pow(ab1, 2)); //second side of the triangle
    T1L3=ab1+cb1; //third side of the triangle
    double p, area;
    p=(T1L1+T1L2+T1L3)/2;
    area=sqrt(p*(p-T1L1)*((p-T1L2)*(p-T1L3)));
    return area;
}
```

The mistake seems to be here :

```
Area = double area(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy);
```

Comment: To call a function you do not need to specify the return type. Omit the `double` before `area`.

Comment: You should define a type for "Area". double Area = area(ax,ay...). See what is declaration and initialization in the c.

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about that `scanf()`, turn up warnings till it does (`-Wall -Wextra` is good for gcc and clang)

Comment: For `double` you must use format spec `%lf` in `scanf()` but just `%f` in `printf()`. Always check the return value from `scanf()` too, here it must be `6`.